# WorkerManger is still auto running when app has already restarted

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I found that when worker is running on the app and then force close it, after that I re-open the app, but the worker is still auto re-running from background without my control...

How can I prevent this issue? How can I cancel this worker?

```
val work = OneTimeWorkRequest
        .Builder(DownloadImageWorker::class.java)
        .build()

    WorkManager.getInstance(App.instance)
        .beginWith(work).enqueue()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WorkManager is for task that needs a guarantee to be run. The behavior you are describing is [**as designed**](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager).

You may want to evaluate other solutions if you don't need to persist a task in this way like Kotlin's Coroutines. You can find more on the [Android's background guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/background).

An option with WorkManager is to manually cancel your WorkRequest. Starting from your code:

```
val work = OneTimeWorkRequest
        .Builder(DownloadImageWorker::class.java)
        .build()

val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(App.instance)
workManager.beginWith(work).enqueue()
```

You can then cancel the workrequest when you need:

```
// Cancel the WorkRequest
workManager.cancelWorkById(work.id)
```

You can find additional information on [WorkManager's documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/managing-work#cancelling).